# Do these lines in 3D space intersect?

Tags: 3d, plane-geometry

Th lines formed by $(0,0,0)+ \lambda(1,1,1)$ and $(0,6,0)+ \lambda(0,-3,2)$ ever intersect? It seems like the do but they don't. How do I show this algebraically?[image]

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: Every point on your second line has $x=0$. Only one point on your first line has. Does that point lie on the second line?

Comment: I used that but still wasn't able to get lambda as a symbol.

Comment: (0,0,0) does not lie on the second line.

Answer (score 2):

The point of intersection should be a point on both $(t,t,t)$ and $(0,6-3s,2s)$

Solving for equality we get $t=0, t=6-3s, t=2s$ which is inconsistent,so there is not point of intersection.

Comment: Thank you. Since we know they do not intersect nor are they parallel, are they skewed?

Comment: Yes, they are skewed as you mentioned.